# Use external icon for JQueryUI

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Is there an easy way to use an external icon for JQuery UI?

Say I have the following icon on a button:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#aButton').button({
            icons: 
            {
                primary: "ui-icon-newicon"
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<button id="aButton">hello</button>
```

Is it possible to display an external jpeg or png? What is the easiest was to do this without editing the existing JQuery UI png files?

I have previously managed to achieve this by manually editing and replacing an icon that I don't use in the `ui-icons_xxxxxx_256x240.png` files which works great until I upgrade to a new version of JQuery UI using nuget and the png files are replaced.

**Edit:**

Created this class in my Site.css (its a ASP.NET MVC3 app) and needed to add the !important flag. Didn't have any issues with state (when the button is highlighted, hover etc).

```
.ui-icon-newicon
{
    background-image: url(images/delete.png) !important;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just add your own file and supply a CSS class for that specific button, something like:

```
#aButton.ui-icon-custom {
    background-image: url(...);
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Would it not make more sense to define a new css class instead of overriding one?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean - yes - see edit.  Note that jQuery will _always_ add the `.ui-icon` class too.

Comment: Ok cool - I'll do some testing now...Think I'll run into issues with states though (hover, highlight etc). You were spot on about the offset: `.ui-icon-locked { background-position: -192px -96px; } .ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsContent}*/; }`

Comment: I don't think jQuery UI changes the icon images for hover - AFAIK it just changes the background colour.

Comment: Works like a charm, just needed to add the !important flag...thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by defining your own style for that class in your css:

```
.ui-icon-locked { background-image: url(images/custom.png); }
```